# PYTHONPATH value in virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have issue with PYTHONPATH while using virtualenv.

1. I have set my PYTHONPATH as below which has python dist-packages are above package of PYTHONPATH value

> export
>   PYTHONPATH=/opt/tangoworkspace/CentralNode/Alarm/Panic_Alarm_Suite:/opt/tangoworkspace/CentralNode/Alarm/Panic_Alarm_Suite/PANIC-master:/opt/tangoworkspace/CentralNode/Alarm/Panic_Alarm_Suite/fandango-master:/opt/tangoworkspace/CentralNode/GUI/src/:/opt/tangoworkspace/CentralNode/Alarm/Panic_Alarm_Suite/PyTangoArchiving:/opt/tangoworkspace/CentralNode/Alarm/Panic_Alarm_Suite/fandango-master/user_login:/opt/software/Cdist/python

2. without starting virtual env value of python **sys.path** is as below:

> ```
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/phonon-2.0-py2.7.egg
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-4.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis-2.10.5-py2.7.egg
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/backports_abc-0.5-py2.7.egg
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/singledispatch-3.4.0.3-py2.7.egg
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.5.0.1-py2.7.egg
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/futures-3.2.0-py2.7.egg
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytango-9.2.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
> /opt/tangoworkspace/CentralNode/Alarm/Panic_Alarm_Suite
> /opt/tangoworkspace/CentralNode/Alarm/Panic_Alarm_Suite/PANIC-master
> /opt/tangoworkspace/CentralNode/Alarm/Panic_Alarm_Suite/fandango-master
> /opt/tangoworkspace/CentralNode/GUI/src
> /opt/tangoworkspace/CentralNode/Alarm/Panic_Alarm_Suite/PyTangoArchiving
> /opt/tangoworkspace/CentralNode/Alarm/Panic_Alarm_Suite/fandango-master/user_login
> /opt/software/Cdist/python
> /usr/lib/python2.7
> /usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
> /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
> /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
> /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
> /home/tcs/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0
> ```

3. after starting virtual env value of sys.path is as below which has packages of PATHONPATH at top.

> ```
> /opt/tangoworkspace/CentralNode/Alarm/Panic_Alarm_Suite
> /opt/tangoworkspace/CentralNode/Alarm/Panic_Alarm_Suite/PANIC-master
> /opt/tangoworkspace/CentralNode/Alarm/Panic_Alarm_Suite/fandango-master
> /opt/tangoworkspace/CentralNode/GUI/src
> /opt/tangoworkspace/CentralNode/Alarm/Panic_Alarm_Suite/PyTangoArchiving
> /opt/tangoworkspace/CentralNode/Alarm/Panic_Alarm_Suite/fandango-master/user_login
> /opt/software/Cdist/python
> /home/tcs/ENV_Python2.7/lib/python2.7
> /home/tcs/ENV_Python2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
> /home/tcs/ENV_Python2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
> /home/tcs/ENV_Python2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
> /home/tcs/ENV_Python2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
> /usr/lib/python2.7
> /usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
> /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
> ```

can any one explain how python set value of sys.path?
can I set **/usr/local/lib/python2.7/** packages at top of sys.path list value in virtualenv ?

Comment: Have you tried the [`--system-site-packages` option](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#the-system-site-packages-option)?

Comment: But that's how it's supposed to be: Packages you install inside the virtualenv end up in that virtualenv. If you want to install packages outside the virtualenv, run `pip` outside of it (I recommend against it though)

Comment: yes, I have tried  --system-site-packages while creating virtual environment but whatever package I installed under virtual env using pip were put under  /home/Hitesh/ENV_Python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages which is below packages of PYTHONPATH list.

Comment: I have observed that in one of my machine sys.path value is [PYTHONPATH, usr/lib/python2.7,dist-packages, site-packages] and other machine have sys.path value is [/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/, PYTHONPATH, /usr/lib/python2.7] . which is right? why there is different in sys.path value sequence ?